# Is it possible to catch 3rd party iOS library exception?

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, crash

My Objective-C application is using a 3rd party VoIP SDK.  I found the application crashes if left running overnight.  The crash only happens if I enable the SDK, so I strongly suspect it causes the crash.

The library is a static library (.a extension).  I tried catching the exception using try-catch block, and NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler, but it didn't work.  I suspect those methods only work with Objective-C exceptions, and the SDK is written in native C?

Is it possible to catch a 3rd party native C exception?  I'm fine with any kind of hacks, since this will not be going into production code.  Just trying to get to the bottom of the issue.

EDIT: 
Here's the crash log:

```
    Hardware Model:      iPad5,1
    Version:             0.14 (6.0)
    Beta:                YES
    Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
    Role:                Foreground
    Parent Process:      launchd [1]


    Date/Time:           2016-11-22 08:24:59.7336 -0500
    Launch Time:         2016-11-21 13:45:09.9956 -0500
    OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.1.1 (14B100)
    Report Version:      104

    Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
    Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
    Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
    Triggered by Thread:  0

    Application Specific Information:
    abort() called

    Filtered syslog:
    None found

    Last Exception Backtrace:
    (0x18953e1c0 0x187f7855c 0x18953e108 0x18f89359c 0x18f6f4444 0x18f4c653c
 0x18f391d48 0x18f391c78 0x18f44bb10 0x18f44aec0 0x18f44a90c 0x18f44a4c0
 0x18f44a424 0x18f38f220 0x18c84f188 0x18c843e64 0x18c843d24 0x18c7c07ec 
0x18c7e7c58 0x18c7e8678 0x1894eb7dc 0x1894e940c 0x1894e989c 0x189418048 
0x18ae9e198 0x18f3fd2fc 0x18f3f8034 0x10002304c 0x1883fc5b8)

    Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    Thread 0 Crashed:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018850e014 0x1884ef000 + 126996
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001885d6450 0x1885d1000 + 21584
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001884823e0 0x18841f000 + 406496
    3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000187f4d2d4 0x187f4c000 + 4820
    4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000187f6acc0 0x187f4c000 + 126144
    5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000187f78844 0x187f70000 + 34884
    6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000187f6766c 0x187f4c000 + 112236
    7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000187f67234 0x187f4c000 + 111156
    8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000187f7871c 0x187f70000 + 34588
    9   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001894180bc 0x18940f000 + 37052
    10  GraphicsServices                0x000000018ae9e198 0x18ae92000 + 49560
    11  UIKit                           0x000000018f3fd2fc 0x18f382000 + 504572
    12  UIKit                           0x000000018f3f8034 0x18f382000 + 483380
    13  Remote                          0x000000010002304c 0x100008000 + 110668
    14  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001883fc5b8 0x1883f8000 + 17848
```

Comment: It would help if you updated your question with details of the crash.

Comment: @rmaddy I added a crash log.

Comment: It would help if it was a symbolicated crash report.

Comment: Any log messages on the console at the time? Many libraries will log before calling abort to help you diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That isn't a catchable exception, that is a hard crash. And, specifically, it is a purposeful crash;  something on the main thread decided things had gone badly enough that it called `abort()`.

So, no, nothing you can do to catch it and it isn't even clear that the crash is triggered by the 3rd party library, given that crash log.